# How to successfully perform file I/O with asynchronous input in Dart using Streams

Tags: dart, asynchronous

I was wondering if anyone knew how to correctly perform asynchronous file I/O in Dart using Streams, because clearly my method is not working. I have seen other people's solutions by converting the stream to a list, but I don't really want to do that because of speed concerns and was wondering if there was any way to do this operation using just streams?

Anyways, here is my code:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:collection';
import 'dart:convert';

final validCharacters = RegExp(r'^[a-zA-Z]+$'); // a-z, A-Z

main() async {
  final dict1File = 'american-english';
  final dict2File = 'british-english';
  final cleanedDictFile = 'Cleansed_English_Dictionary';
  SplayTreeSet<String> wordSet = new SplayTreeSet<String>();
  await readFile(dict1File, wordSet);
  await readFile(dict2File, wordSet);
  await writeFile(cleanedDictFile, wordSet);
}

readFile(String fileName, SplayTreeSet<String> wordSet) async {
  File file = new File(fileName);
  if (await file.exists()) {
    file
        .openRead()
        .transform(Utf8Decoder())
        .transform(LineSplitter())
        .where((String data) => validCharacters.hasMatch(data))
        .listen((String data) => wordSet.add(data),
            onDone: () => print('${wordSet.length}'), onError: (e) => print(e));
  } else {
    print('The desired file $fileName does not exist');
  }
}

writeFile(String fileName, SplayTreeSet<String> wordSet) async {
  File file = new File(fileName);
  if (await file.exists()) {
        file.openWrite().writeAll(wordSet, '\n');
  } else {
    print('The desired file $fileName does not exist');
  }
}
```

Here is me performing a similar operation in Java (my native language) :p

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class DictCleaner {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Beginning process");
    Set<String> words = new TreeSet<>();
    long time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    readFile("american-english", words);
    readFile("british-english", words);
    long time2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(
      "Time to read files: " + (time2 - time1) + " milliseconds"
    );
    System.out.println("Number of words: " + words.size());
    String filename = "Cleansed_English_Dictionary";
    System.out.println("Outputting new file, " + filename);
    outputFile(filename, words);
    long time3 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(
      "Total execution time: " + (time3 - time1) + " milliseconds"
    );
    File file = new File(filename);
    double fileSize = file.length() >> 10;
    System.out.println(
      "Output file size of " + filename + "= " + fileSize + " kilobytes"
    );
  }

  public static void readFile(String fileName, Set<String> words)
    throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br;
    try {
      br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
      String currentLine;
      while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (currentLine.matches("^[a-zA-Z]") && currentLine.length() <= 15) {
          words.add(currentLine);
        }
      }
      br.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
      ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void outputFile(String filename, Set<String> words)
    throws FileNotFoundException {
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(
      new FileOutputStream(filename)
    );
    try {
      for (String s : words) {
        bos.write(s.getBytes());
        bos.write(System.lineSeparator().getBytes());
      }
      bos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Anyways, I am basically just cleaning up a dictionary for use with my app. Does anyone have any guidance on how I can make the Dart code work, or perhaps a more generic explanation?

**My new code after comments!**

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:collection';
import 'dart:convert';

final validCharacters = RegExp(r'^[a-zA-Z]+$'); // a-z, A-Z

main() async {
  Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch()..start();
  final dict1File = 'american-english';
  final dict2File = 'british-english';
  final cleanedDictFile = 'Cleansed_English_Dictionary';
  SplayTreeSet<String> wordSet = new SplayTreeSet<String>();
  await readFile(dict1File, wordSet);
  await readFile(dict2File, wordSet);
  await writeFile(cleanedDictFile, wordSet);
  print('Total execution time: ${stopwatch.elapsed}');
}

Future<void> readFile(String fileName, SplayTreeSet<String> wordSet) async {
  File file = new File(fileName);
  if (await file.exists()) {
    await for (final data in file
        .openRead()
        .transform(Utf8Decoder())
        .transform(LineSplitter())
        .where((String data) => validCharacters.hasMatch(data))) {
      wordSet.add(data);
    }
    print('${wordSet.length}');
  } else {
    print('The desired file $fileName does not exist');
  }
}

Future<void> writeFile(String fileName, SplayTreeSet<String> wordSet) async {
  File file = new File(fileName);
  if (await file.exists()) {
    IOSink sink = file.openWrite();
    sink.writeAll(wordSet, '\n');
    sink.close();
  } else {
    print('The desired file $fileName does not exist');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `.listen` does not halt the program until all events has been consumed.

I think the most clean way to fix this is to use "await for-each" like this:

```
Future<void> readFile(String fileName, SplayTreeSet<String> wordSet) async {
  File file = new File(fileName);
  if (await file.exists()) {
    await for (final data in file
        .openRead()
        .transform(Utf8Decoder())
        .transform(LineSplitter())
        .where((String data) => validCharacters.hasMatch(data))) {
      wordSet.add(data);
    }
    print('${wordSet.length}');
  } else {
    print('The desired file $fileName does not exist');
  }
}
```

### More optimized solution

As requested, I have tried to make the program run faster. If performance are the main goal, you can often save some time by using the "sync" edition of the IO file operations. In this case, the program are really not doing anything else, so it is fine to let the main thread wait on e.g. reading the file.

One optimization is more about code readability but Dart does already provide `readAsLines` and `readAsLinesSync` on `File` so we don't need to use a Utf8Decoder and LineSplitter if we just want to split the lines. This will potentially take some more memory since we now get a list containing all lines instead of iterating each line. The list are short-lived so it is properly not a problem for this program. But also, the list contains `String` objects where most of them are going to be used in our `Set` so most of the used memory is not really something we can avoid.

Another optimization is the writing. Here we generate the final string first in memory (`wordSet.join('\n')`) and then write the whole string to disk as one operation. This is much faster but does take some additional memory.

```
import 'dart:collection';
import 'dart:io';

final validCharacters = RegExp(r'^[a-zA-Z]+$'); // a-z, A-Z

void main() {
  const dict1File = 'american-english-insane';
  const dict2File = 'british-english-insane';
  const cleanedDictFile = 'Cleansed_English_Dictionary';

  final wordSet = SplayTreeSet<String>();
  readFile(dict1File, wordSet);
  readFile(dict2File, wordSet);
  writeFile(cleanedDictFile, wordSet);
}

void readFile(String fileName, Set<String> wordSet) {
  final file = File(fileName);
  if (file.existsSync()) {
    file
        .readAsLinesSync()
        .where((data) => validCharacters.hasMatch(data))
        .forEach(wordSet.add);
    print(wordSet.length);
  } else {
    print('The desired file $fileName does not exist');
  }
}

void writeFile(String fileName, Iterable<String> wordSet) =>
    File(fileName).writeAsStringSync(wordSet.join('\n'));
```

Comment: You could as well just use `.forEach` instead of an await for-each loop, eg `await ...where((String data) ...).forEach(wordSet.add)`

Comment: @Mattia You are right and I did consider this solution but I don't really like using the `forEach` method in general and especially not on `Stream` if you are going to `await` the returned `Future` right away. Therefore my "most clean way" note in my answer. :)

Comment: Thanks again for the solution, I just ran it and it worked perfectly, but it ran a bit slower than my Java solution (Java is supposed to be the slow poke), would you happen to know why this is the case? @julemand101

Comment: "Java is supposed to be the slow poke" what? Java can have extremely good performance in a lot of cases and it is not unusual that Java can perform better than Dart (the Java JVM is a more mature project and received a lot more optimizations). But if performance is important, it is possible to write your Dart implementation in a more efficient way. But if I should hunt for performance I really need example input to the program so I can actually run the code.

Comment: Also, how has you performed the test? If it is from cold start, it can make the program faster if you compile it first by using dart2native since you can then skip the parsing of the source code at launch and a lot of optimization steps. (but then again, you can do the same for Java programs and make them also faster... :P)

Comment: @julemand101 I am using a dictionary wordlist, so its basically just a bunch of words line by line. And it looks like the handicap is in my writing to the file. (The dictionaries I am using are located at /usr/dict/words if you are using Linux). Also, that's kind of cool that Java is faster than Dart, I always thought that if you were using the same data structures, languages that compile to C/C++ would blow Java out of the water.

Comment: @NateWaltz Dart does not compile to C or C++. Dart and Java can be compared since they are both garbage collected languages and the Dart VM operates in a similar way as the Java VM with the differences that the Dart VM takes Dart source code and Java VM wants compiled bytecode. But both VM's will then translate the code to native code. But C/C++ code can often be written in a even more efficient way. But in a lot of cases, we don't need that efficiency but wants instead easy to write code in languages which handles e.g. memory for us. :)

Comment: I'm running Linux Mint 20, and it looks like the packages are owned by https://packages.debian.org/sid/wordlist. I am using the American insane and the british insane as my wordlists. Dang, so Dart is comparable to Java, are there any benefits to learning Dart then if I already know the ins and outs of Java?

Comment: Well, I am working as a Java developer and uses Dart mostly as a scripting language since Dart code are much quicker to create, deploy and run than even a simple Java program. But for bigger applications I would use Java because jar files are rather nice. :)

Comment: I was looking at using Flutter instead of Java in my Android Apps, it did look like there was a lot less code to write and it did look a lot more concise haha

Comment: I am primary a backend developer so have still not looked at Flutter. ;)

Comment: (I got you program running and can also observe the writing is really slow. I will try optimize the program).

Comment: @NateWaltz I have updated my answer with a more optimized solution.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a bunch. I'm guessing that a lot of the speedup has to do with the writeAsStringSync keyword? OH wait nevermind you addressed that